# Declare an object as abstract class

Tags: c++, qt, oop, abstract-class

**Edit** this question as originally posted was a simplified version of what I had and as such did not contain the problem which was causing the error. I have updated to be more like my problem, and will post an answer in case someone else has a similar issue.

In C++ is it possible to declare an object as an abstract class, but then instantiate it to a derived class?

Take this modified version of example code, gotten from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm

```
class Shape {
   public:
      // pure virtual function providing interface framework.
      virtual int getArea() = 0;
      virtual int getNumOfSides() = 0;
      void setWidth(int w) {
         width = w;
      }
   
      void setHeight(int h) {
         height = h;
      }
   
   protected:
      int width;
      int height;
};
 
// Derived classes
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
      int getArea() { 
         return (width * height); 
      }
};

class Triangle: public Shape {
   public:
      int getArea() { 
         return (width * height)/2; 
      }
};
 
int main(void) {
   Rectangle Rect;
   Triangle  Tri;
 
   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);
   
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Rectangle area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   Tri.setWidth(5);
   Tri.setHeight(7);
   
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Triangle area: " << Tri.getArea() << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

However, if we don't know the type of the Shape at compile time, is it possible to do something like:

```
Shape *shape;

if (userInput == 'R') {
   shape = new Rectangle();
} else if (userInput == 'T') {
   shape = new Triangle();
}

// etc.
```

... as can be done in C#?

I have tried that but got the error:

> error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Rectangle'

This is within QT.

Comment: `Shape* shape;`

Comment: In C# an identifier like `shape` is basically a smart pointer. In C++ there is a very important distinction between an instance of an object and a pointer to an object. `Shape shape;` tries to define a whole `Shape` object, which it can't (it's abstract). You want a pointer to a `Shape`. Consider `std::unique_ptr<Shape> shape;` instead.

Comment: Which compiler gave you that error? It's weird because `Rectangle` is not abstract. When I tried it, I got rather different error messages: `error: cannot declare variable 'shape' to be of abstract type 'Shape'` (as expected when defining `shape`) and **`error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Shape' and 'Rectangle*')`** (when assigning `new Rectangle`) and **`error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Shape' and 'Triangle*')`** (when assigning `new Triangle`). The asterisks in the latter messages are highly significant.

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the detail, this is QT and I had declared it as a pointer - I've edited the post.

Comment: I have a confession to make, I hadn't posted the complete code, this was a highly simplified version, to avoid having to share confidential code and for simplicity. The actual code was different and contained an issue that this did not, which made this question unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that not *all* of the virtual functions defined by the abstract class were implemented in the derived classes.

I needed

```
// Derived classes
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
     int getArea() { 
        return (width * height); 
     }
     int getNumOfSides() {
        return 4;
     }
};

class Triangle: public Shape {
   public:
     int getArea() { 
        return (width * height)/2; 
     }
     int getNumOfSides() {
        return 3;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> In C++ is it possible to declare an object as an abstract class, but then instantiate it to a derived class?

You cannot declare an *object*, no.  Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  However, you can declare a *reference*/*pointer* to an object that implements an abstract class, yes.  For example:

```cpp
Shape *shape;

if (userInput == 'R') {
   shape = new Rectangle();
} else if (userInput == 'T') {
   shape = new Triangle();
}

// etc.

delete shape;
```

In C++11 and later, you can use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to automatically call `delete` for you when the pointer goes out of scope, eg:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Shape> shape;

if (userInput == 'R') {
   shape.reset(new Rectangle);
   // or: shape = std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Rectangle);
   // or: shape = std::make_unique<Rectangle>(); // C++14 and later only
} else if (userInput == 'T') {
   shape.reset(new Triangle);
   // or: shape = std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle);
   // or: shape = std::make_unique<Triangle>(); // C++14 and later only
}

// etc.
```

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape;

if (userInput == 'R') {
   shape.reset(new Rectangle);
   // or: shape = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
} else if (userInput == 'T') {
   shape.reset(new Triangle);
   // or: shape = std::make_shared<Triangle>();
}

// etc.
```

Either way, just make sure that `Shape` has a `virtual` destructor, so that the correct derived destructor will be called when `delete`'ing a derived object via a `Shape*` pointer:

```cpp
class Shape {
   public:
      virtual ~Shape() {}
   // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your program memory-safe, you can use `std::shared_ptr` this way:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
using ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;

class Shape { ... };
class Rectangle: public Shape { ... };
class Triangle: public Shape { ... };
 
int main() 
{
    ptr Rect = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
    ptr Tri = std::make_shared<Triangle>();

    // Notice you have to use '->' instead of '.', since those are (smart) pointers
    Rect->setWidth(5);
    Rect->setHeight(7);

    cout << "Total Rectangle area: " << Rect->getArea() << endl;

    Tri->setWidth(5);
    Tri->setHeight(7);

    cout << "Total Triangle area: " << Tri->getArea() << endl; 

    // Can't use CTAD as for Rect and Tri. We have to specify 'Shape'.
    ptr<Shape> shape;

    char userInput;
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == 'R') {
        shape = std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
    } else if (userInput == 'T') {
        shape = std::make_shared<Triangle>();
    }

    cout << shape->getArea() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `shared_ptr` and not `unique_ptr`?  The `Shape` pointer is not actually being shared in this example, so `shared_ptr` is needless overhead.

Comment: If you need polymorphism, you're usually better off with with shared_ptr.

Comment: `unique_ptr` works just fine with polymorphic types. The only advantage of `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr` is the reference counting, and that is not required for polymorphism.

Comment: Sure, until he needs to copy his pointers somewhere else or use [one of those](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). Forcing unique_ptr as a default choice over shared_ptr is just premature optimization.

Comment: "*Sure, until he needs to copy his pointers somewhere else*" - that is what move semantics are for. Not that hard to manage a `unique_ptr` properly. "*or use one of those*" - honestly, I have never seen those used in real production code. "*Forcing unique_ptr as a default choice over shared_ptr is just premature optimization*" - and forcing `shared_ptr` as a default is wasted overhead when it is not commonly needed.

Comment: Good luck copying pointers with move semantics only. OP comes from C#, do you think he's aware unique_ptr won't allow him to have multiple references to a single object across his code?

Comment: If you need to hold *multiple* references to an object, then obviously you have to use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`. More times than not, `unique_ptr` will suffice, though.  I'm just saying, `shared_ptr` is not a requirement to use polymorphism in general. Both `ptr`s work with polymorphism, and both have their particular use-cases.